# Modifying Images on Webpage with Web Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a web extension that goes through all the images in the current webpage and blurs them. I have created a backend API that accepts a base64 encoded string of an image and returns the encoded string for the blurred image. My current issue is that I can't find a way to access all the images on the current webpage and get their base64 encoded string through javascript. How can I do this?
The intended architecture of the extension is as follows: the javascript file reads all the images on the webpage and encodes them into a base64 string, which is passed to the backend API. The API then blurs the image and returns a base64 encoded string of the blurred image. The javascript then decodes the string and replaces the original image with the blurred image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried going through all the image tags in the html of the webpage and fetching their urls, however this does not allow me to get the base64 encoding of the image(s). I would like to write a function that takes in the url to an image and returns the base64 encoding.

Comment: If you just want to blur it, it's easy to inject CSS.

Comment: Do you want to blur the images in irreversible way?
Note that if the web page contains many (and big) images this strategy (sending and receiving base64 strings to\from a backend) might introduce considerable network traffic\lag

Comment: @NorioYamamoto There is some other processing that is being done to determine which images to blur, so injecting CSS will not work.

Comment: @Shkev You can inject CSS dynamically, see [chrome.scripting > insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-insertCSS) and removeCSS.